# why “mov” instruction cost so much time

Tags: performance, assembly, x86-64, perf

I profile my code by linux perf, but the results are not so easy to understand. Why does the mov cost so much time in the following code?

```
55.85 │      mov    %rdx,-0x48(%rbp)
```

Could anyone help on that?

```
 15.93 │      mov    -0x48(%rbp),%rax                                                                                                                                               
  0.00 │      mov    %rdx,%rcx                                                                                                                                                      
       │      mov    %rdx,-0x50(%rbp)                                                                                                                                               
  0.59 │      xor    %edx,%edx                                                                                                                                                      
  0.12 │      div    %rsi                                                                                                                                                           
  6.96 │      mov    %rcx,%rax                                                                                                                                                      
  0.00 │      not    %ecx                                                                                                                                                           
       │      shr    $0x3,%rax                                                                                                                                                      
  0.62 │      and    $0x7,%ecx                                                                                                         
  0.17 │      movzbl 0x20(%r14,%rax,1),%eax                                                                                                                                         
  55.85│      mov    %rdx,-0x48(%rbp)    <= here
  0.02 │      sar    %cl,%eax
```

c code is here for reference:

```
struct resource {
    uint64_t  magic_num;
    uint64_t  m;
    uint64_t  k;
    uint64_t  count;
    unsigned char c_vector[1];
};
#define get_array(v, n)    ((v)[(n) >> 3] &  (0x1 << (0x7 - ((n) & 0x7))))
int
compute_result(const struct resource *res, const void *key, size_t len)
{
    uint32_t i;
    uint64_t  result[2];

    for (i = 0; i < res->k; i++) {
        get_x64_result(key, len, i, &result);
        result[0] %= res->m;
        result[1] %= res->m;
        if (!get_array(res->c_vector, result[0])){
            return 0;
        }
        if (!get_array(res->c_vector, result[1])){
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
```

}

maybe i can check if (result and res->m) < 0xffffffff then use 32bit div, but not sure could help.

Comment: It looks like it's the first thing that reads an output from `div`.  64-bit `div` is very slow on Intel, much slower than 32-bit operand-size.  Another `mov` overwrites the RAX output (quotient) to calculate an array index for movzx.  Is this from an Intel CPU or AMD?  On AMD, `div r64` is still only 2 uops and isn't slower for the same input value.

Comment: Thanks! @PeterCordes, you are right, first move is read output from div. This is from Intel CPU, by the way is there any method to improve the performance?

Comment: Use `div` less often, or use `div %esi` instead if you're sure inputs are only 32-bit.  Or if the divisor is a compile-time constant, make sure constant-propagation can happen so your compiler can use a multiplicative inverse.  Or if there are any commonly-used divisors, maybe special case check for them; a reasonably-predictable branch is usually worth avoiding a div, especially for 64-bit operand-size.

Comment: Or if your inputs are usually small but in rare cases can be 64-bit, either check for that or get an AMD CPU instead.

Comment: ```mov    -0x48(%rbp),%rax ```  uses ```rax``` but ```rax``` is used in ```div```, so if avoid using ```rax```,  maybe can improv performance? So can i improve performance by change the order of instruction? Suppose I can embed ASM in my code

Comment: Well sure, maybe using a different dividend could help, e.g. letting `div` start sooner without an input dependency on that local variable.  But how can you do that without totally changing what this code does?  And no, hand-written asm isn't usually helpful; it doesn't matter whether machine code comes from compiler-generated asm or hand-written asm.  BTW, I assume this is compiler output.  You are compiling with optimizations enabled, right?  Like `gcc -O3 -march=native -flto`, and preferably profile-guided optimization.  I only ask because your code is using `%rbp` instead of `%rsp`.

Comment: This could be an interesting discussion - but only on the basis of a [mcve] and a clear system description. Otherwise there is just too much guessing.

Comment: It's part of a complicated program, i will post the function here for reference.